# Need help identifying this Benq Projector Lamp connector

Tags: identification, connector

This is for a Benq W770ST. The mating connector in the projector fell apart when replacing the bulb.

[image: Benq Lamp Connector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [TE - Mini-Universal MATE-N-LOK (1r)](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=partitioned_shroud_round_conn&s=Mini-Universal%20MATE-N-LOK%20(1r)) (my site).

[TE 172166-1](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/172166-1/333002)

[image: TE 172166-1]

{Digikey}